# jQuery- Get all hyperlinked images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to do something with each hyperlinked image within a div with class of `sampleclass`:

```
<div class="sampleclass">
  <a href="#">text hyperlink</a> <!-- don't touch this -->
  <a href="#"><img src="image.jpg"></a> <!-- only touch this -->
</div>
```

Here is what I have:

```
$('.sampleclass a > img').(function() {
    $(this).addClass("someotherclass");
});
```

This doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: In what way isn't this working?

Comment: you want to add the class to anchor or the image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something is missing here.

```
$('.sampleclass a > img').(function() {
    $(this).addClass("someotherclass");
});
```

This:

```
$('.sampleclass a > img').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("someotherclass");
});
```

Note that if you're only doing simple things like that, you can also omit the call to each `.each()`.

```
$('.sampleclass a > img').addClass("someotherclass");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.sampleclass a > img').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("someotherclass");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to fix it:

```
 $('.sampleclass a > img').addClass("someotherclass");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KFg2H/)